# return pointer from a function in c

Tags: c, pointers

> Write function that gets a string `s` and char `c` that checks whether the char shows in `s`, if yes return a pointer to the first place that `c` shows in `s`

Here is my code. I am not sure what I did about "return the pointer", is this correct?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *foo(char s[], char c)
{
    int i;
    char *ptr;
    for(i=0;s[i];i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==c)
        {
            printf("result: %d",i);
            *ptr=i;
            return ptr;
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    char s[]="Error404";// some string
    char c='r';// some char
    foo(s,c);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just run it and check the result? From the look of it, it won't damage your computer. Also, do something with the returned value.

Comment: No, what you did is not correct. Which a simple test would have revealed to you. What is `ptr` *pointing at*, do you think?

Comment: What if the condition `s[i]==c` is never true? What do you return then?

Comment: Also, when you do `*ptr=i`, where does `ptr` point? And should you return the index or the current position in `s` (which is `&s[i]`)?

Comment: Should be `int main(void)`.  `void main()` is not C standard.

Comment: This is what GDB says: `0  0x00000000004005e2 in foo (s=0x7fffffffe170 "Error404", c=114 'r') at xx.c:11
        i = 1
        ptr = 0x0`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  if the condition `s[i]==c` is never true, return `null` or something similiar

Comment: But if the condition is never true, you don't return *anything* right now, and that will lead to *undefined behavior*. Just like dereferencing an uninitialized pointer like `ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your specification is unclear. Before you start coding, make sure that the specification makes sense. It doesn't say what to do if you *don't* find the character, so you can't write this function before you know that.

Your function must always return something, even if the character was not found. A common way to implement this would be to return a null pointer in that case.

Your pointer should point at the found character, not at `i` which is an integer, that doesn't make any sense.

Correct the code into something like this:

```
char* foo (char s[], char c)
{
    char *ptr = NULL;

    for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==c)
        {
            ptr = &s[i]; // point at the address of item number i in s
            break;
        }
    }

    return ptr; // will return NULL if not found, otherwise a pointer to the found item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is a string, then `s[i]` represents the ith char in the string, while `s + i` represents a pointer to the ith char in the string. So you want to return `s + i`. You probably also want to return `NULL` if the char is not found.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *foo(char s[], char c)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; s[i]; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == c)
            return (s + i);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: This is not enough to fix all bugs in the function though.

Comment: Here's what I find odd. If you return `ptr` right after setting it, why bother having it at all